# Hiding and showing element based on screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make button that will hide and show menu when web page is being displayed on smaller screens. I want to keep the whole menu when the display is wider than 640px. I'm only allowed to use CSS and JavaScript.

Here is the JS function I wrote:

```
var b = document.getElementById ("menu-button");
b.addEventListener("click", showMenu, false);
var i = 0;
function showMenu () {
    i++;
    if(i % 2 == 1)
        document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "block";
    else
        document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "none";
}
```

It is working when displaying the page on smaller screen.

When I click the button to hide the menu (that changes "menu" display to `none`) and then increase the size of the page, my menu does not appear when the screen becomes larger than 640px.

This media media query does not do the job:

```
@media screen and (min-width:640px) {
    #menu {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `!important` to the CSS property, like:

```
 #menu { display:block!important; }
```

Your Javascript adds `style` attribute to the element, which has [higher priority](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) than any internal or external CSS styles, unless they "are" `!important`.

What you can also consider doing to avoid that is to toggle some CSS class in your Javascript instead of setting `style` attribute. This way you avoid using `!important`.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to not set an elements `style` like that, toggle a class on the element is the recommended way

*Side note, I also changed from `id` to `class`, which is also recommended*

*Also, [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) is the reason, pointed out already in comments/answers, why your code doesn't work, more to read here: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity_)*

```js
var b = document.querySelector(".menu-button");
b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  document.querySelector(".menu").classList.toggle("show");
});
```

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
}
.menu.show {
  display: block;
}


@media screen and (min-width:640px) {
    .menu {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu show">Hi, I'm a menu element</div>
<button class="menu-button">Show/Hide</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your tips, I replaced all IDs with class names. But I have some problem with using classList.toggle("show"), it doesn't do anything when I click on button. If I change it to document.querySelector(".menu").style.display = "block" then it shows menu. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: @Bouhraoua You need to add the CSS rule `.show` as well to your style sheet. And don't start using `style.display = 'block'` way of coding, it is really a bad way of achieving what you look for

Answer (score 2):

Connexo has pointed out the answer but an expansion may be of some use to you and others who come here in the future.

The 'style' of an HTML element can be set in at least 3 places. The browser will have to decide which should win should there be a clash. The rules used are called 'specificity'. There is a good article on this topic here https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ if you want a fuller explanation.

Roughly, any styling defined in the initial HTML 'style' attribute is most powerful so this will win in over a CSS file rule. Importantly, setting the style as you have done in your use case, operates on the HTML style attribute.

Therefore, your CSS is being overruled by the style attribute setting in your code.

For a pure JS solution you could look at adding a listener to the window onResize event. If you do research that approach please be aware that in some browsers the event fires for every pixel of the size change, so look for a solution that takes that into consideration like [this one](http://mbccs.blogspot.co.uk/2007/11/fixing-window-resize-event-in-ie.html) otherwise the function will be triggered multiple times and may reduce the joy you bring to your users.

Comment: Check out window.matchMedia & addListener.

Answer (score 0):

As other comments suggested, you are trying different things in your code.
I recommend a css solution, you can look into what most grids use to style their media queries to show / hide elements when browserwindow is being resized or the monitorsize becomes smaller.

A very cool, light-weight grid is called simplegrid.

https://github.com/ThisIsDallas/Simple-Grid/blob/master/simplegrid.css

at line 177 the media query for 'handheld' devices start.
So for instance adding this to your HTML document:

```
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://github.com/ThisIsDallas/Simple-Grid/blob/master/simplegrid.css">
</head>
<body>
<button class="hide-on-mobile">MyButton</button>
</body>
```

The button will not be visible if the browser window is beneath 767px

Answer (score -1):

You need to add !important to the css property. Because your JavaScript code is setting the element style attribute which has more priority than any css selector styles.

Comment: Adding that to the selector would mean `#menu !important { display: block; }`. You probably meant to postfix the value in the CSS rule with `!important`.

Comment: Sorry, i meant adding it to the display property afcourse.

Comment: What is a "css selector property"? I think you need to get the terms straight. Selectors don't have properties.

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: It was mistake and he apologized for it.
Anyway, this is the answer I was looking for, because I didn't know about !important. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, just tried to help. Anyway, happy your problem is fixed.